# Java Simon Says

Tags: java, stack, queue

I currently have the GUI made for a simon says game, the only problem I'm having is implementing the game logic (my current code will generate a sequence and display user input, but won't save the generated sequence, or compare it to the input). I know I have to use either a queue or a stack, but I can't figure out how to implement either of these to make a working game.

Can someone please help, here's what I got so far:

Driver:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Location 
{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Location");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new LocationPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

"Location Panel" (Simon says game logic):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.Random;

public class LocationPanel extends JPanel 
{

    private final int WIDTH =300, HEIGHT=300;   // dimensions of window
    private int[] xLoc, yLoc;       // locations for target boxes
        /*      0       1
                2       3   */

    private int timer;      // timer for displaying user clicks
    private int xClick, yClick; // location of a user click

    private int sTimer;     // timer for displaying target
    private int[] target;       // choice of target

    private int currTarget;
    private int numTargets;

    private JButton pushButton; // button for playing next sequence

    public LocationPanel() 
    {
        xLoc = new int[4];
        yLoc = new int[4];
        xLoc[0] = 100;  yLoc[0] = 100;
        xLoc[1] = 200;  yLoc[1] = 100;
        xLoc[2] = 100;  yLoc[2] = 200;
        xLoc[3] = 200;  yLoc[3] = 200;

        timer = 0;
        sTimer = 0;

        xClick = -100;  yClick = -100;
        target = new int[10];
        currTarget = -1;

        pushButton = new JButton("Next Sequence");
        pushButton.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
        add(pushButton);

        addMouseListener(new MouseHandler()); 
        setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        setBackground (Color.white);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics page) 
    {
        super.paintComponent(page);

        // draw four target area boxes
        page.setColor(Color.black);
        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) 
        {
            page.drawRect(xLoc[i]-20, yLoc[i]-20, 40, 40);
        }

        // if are displaying a target, draw it
        if (sTimer>0)
        {
            page.setColor(Color.blue);
            page.fillOval(xLoc[target[currTarget]]-15, yLoc[target[currTarget]]-15, 30, 30);
            sTimer--;
            repaint();
        }
        if (sTimer == 0) 
        {
            if (currTarget < numTargets - 1) 
            {
                currTarget++;
                sTimer = 500;
            } 
            else 
            {
                sTimer--;
            }
        }

        // if are displaying a user click, draw it
        if (timer>0) 
        {
            page.setColor(Color.red);
            page.fillOval(xClick-15, yClick-15, 30, 30);
            timer--;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    // when the button is pressed, currently the program selects a single
    // random target location and displays the target there for a short time
    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
        {
            Random gen = new Random();
            numTargets = target.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < target.length; i++) 
            {
                int insert = gen.nextInt(4);

                if(i == 0)
                    target[i] = insert;
                else
                {
                    while(insert == target[i - 1])
                            insert = gen.nextInt(4);

                    target[i] = insert;
                }
            }
            currTarget = 0;
            sTimer = 500;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    // when the user clicks the mouse, this method registers the click and
    // draws a circle there for a short time
    private class MouseHandler implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener 
    {
        // the method that is called when the mouse is clicked - note that Java is very picky that a click does
        // not include any movement of the mouse; if you move the mouse while you are clicking that is a
        // "drag" and this method is not called
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) 
        {
            // get the X and Y coordinates of where the  mouse was clicked 
            xClick = event.getX();
            yClick = event.getY();
            System.out.println("(" + xClick + "," + yClick + ")");

            // the repaint( ) method calls the paintComponent method, forcing the application window to be redrawn
            timer = 50;
            repaint();
        }
        // Java requires that the following six methods be included in a MouseListener class, but they need
        // not have any functionality provided for them
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {}
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {}
    }
```

}

Comment: 'Clean Code' by Robert Martin.  Can't answer your question but the book will help ultimately.

Comment: For us who don't know the game, you could have put at least a [link to some description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_says).

Comment: @David: Why can't you answer? Why will the book help?

Comment: I think that the explanation in wiki will clear a few things for you: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(data_structure)

Comment: Well i'm confused on how to compare the input to the given sequence

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: I'm guessing this is supposed to model [Simon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simon_%28game%29).

Comment: Damnit, I put a bounty on the wrong question...again, thanks for the great answers, but I solved it after the first 2...

Comment: If you've solved it, please mark the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the Javadoc for Queue

[Queue (Java 2 Platform SE 5.0)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

1. Start by saving the generated sequence inside your `ButtonListener`.  Create a Queue Inside your `ButtonListener`:

   ```
   Queue<Integer> generatedSequence = new Queue<Integer>();
   ```
2. Populate the queue with the randoms as you generate them.
3. Then, inside your `mouseClicked` event handler, **pop** items off of the queue and check to see if they are the same as the mouse clicked region.

Answer (score 6):

Describing this seemed complex, so I made a console example:

```
public static class SimonSays {
    private final Random r;
    private final int simonNR = 4;
    private final ArrayList<Integer> nrs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private final Queue<Integer> hits = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    public SimonSays(Random r, int nr) {
        this.r = r;

        for (int i = 0; i < nr - 1; i++)
            this.nrs.add(r.nextInt(this.simonNR));
    }
    private void next() {
        this.nrs.add(r.nextInt(this.simonNR));
        this.hits.clear();
        this.hits.addAll(this.nrs);
    }
    public boolean hasTargets() {
        return hits.size() > 0;
    }
    public Integer[] targets() {
        return nrs.toArray(new Integer[nrs.size()]);
    }
    public boolean hit(Integer i) {
        Integer val = hits.poll();
        if (val.compareTo(i) == 0) return true;
        return false;
    }
    public void play() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean b = true;

        do {
            this.next();
            System.out.println("Simon says: " + 
                Arrays.toString(this.targets()));
            while (hasTargets()) {
                System.out.print("You say: ");
                if ((b = hit(sc.nextInt())) == false) break;
            }
        } while (b);

        System.out.println("\nYou made to size: " + this.nrs.size());
    }
}
```

To play : <kbd>`new SimonSays(new Random(/*for fixed results enter seed*/), 3).play();`</kbd>.

You just need to rewire play method.

Comment: I like it! Good use of Scanner.

Answer (score 4):

I would save the generated sequence in a `List`. Then get an `Iterator` of this List.
(*) Now you just compare the user input with the List item the Iterator points to. If it's different: abort, if it's the same: call `next()` on the iterator and repeat the process at * until you walked through the complete list.
Well you could use a `Queue`, too as gmoore wrote. The principle remains the same, instead using an iterator you would call `remove()` or `poll()` from the queue.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need anything more than an `ArrayList`. Replace your `int[] target` with:

```
private List<Integer> targets = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

When it's time to add a new random target number to the sequence use:

```
targets.add(new Random().nextInt(4));
```

For display you can get the current target number with:

```
int targetNum = targets.get(currTarget);
```

Use another variable to track the position of the user input as they play it back, e.g. `int currUser`. Set it to 0 each round and increment it as they get the sequence right, by checking with `targets.get(currUser)`. You can also replace `numTargets` with `targets.size()`.

When it's time to start over:

```
targets.clear();
```